# Prove or disprove a FOL sentence using relevant domain diagrams: $\exists x (a.x\to b.x) \to (\forall x\,\, ax \to \exists b.x)$

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> Prove or disprove the FOL sentence using relevant domain diagrams:
>   $$\exists x (a.x\to b.x) \to (\forall x\,\, a.x \to \exists x\, b.x)$$

Can you suggest me a way to prove or disprove above two predicate expression using relevant domain diagrams containing elements with properties $a$ and $b$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "$.$" mean?

Comment: Do you think the statement is true or false? Deciding is the first step.

Comment: . means a property for x

Comment: @GFauxPas I imagine "$a.x$" means that $x$ has property $a$

Comment: I suppose it is $a(x)$.

Comment: can you explain more? sorry I didnt get it @James

Comment: Then what does "$\exists b.x$" mean? Confusing.

Comment: You have been asked to prove or disprove the formula. Which do you think is the correct option?

Comment: It is terrible how we "logicians" are able to use the symbols in infinitely different weird ways, with the result that we are "sinning" against the first precept of logic: to ensure clarity and rigour and "understandability"...

Comment: sorry I have made a typing mistake. Now I have edited it

Comment: @James I think its true

Comment: if so is it enough to convert the fol  sentence into CNF and show that both sides are equal? @James

Comment: @GFauxPas Firstly, yes you can bind twice, and secondly, given standard conventions for how things bind, I think its clear the intention is that the consequent is $((\forall x a.x) \rightarrow (\exists x b.x))$.

Comment: You only have one "side" so I don't know to what you will show the formula is equal. Usually, if you want to establish a statement of the form $\phi \rightarrow \psi$, you proceed by assuming $\phi$ and proving $\psi$. In this case, assume $\exists x(a.x \rightarrow b.x)$ and prove $(\forall x a.x \rightarrow \exists x b.x)$. You've been explicitly told to use "domain diagrams" though and I'm not entirely sure what those are.

Comment: yeah that's what I meant. (equal is not the most correct word) thanks a lot. this was a given question and yeah I am confused with those domain diagrams term